# CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: invert-helper in this context

Tags: clojure

I'm pretty new to closure and I don't understand why I'm getting this error message at runtime. Here is my code:

```
(defn invert [lst]
  (if (empty? lst)
    ()
    (cons (invert-helper lst) (invert (rest lst)))))

(defn invert-helper [lst]
  (list (nth lst 1) (first lst)))
```

Comment: You need to define invert-helper before using it in invert.

Answer (score 3):

This should fix the problem:

```
(defn invert-helper [lst]
  (list (nth lst 1) (first lst)))

(defn invert [lst]
  (if (empty? lst)
    ()
    (cons (invert-helper lst) (invert (rest lst)))))
```

That is: the `invert-helper` function must be defined before its first use in `invert`.

Comment: that makes sense, but now I'm getting and index out of bounds exception  clojure.lang.RT.nthFrom (RT.java:795).

Comment: @ChrisPhillips You're calling `(nth lst 1)` where `lst` may have only one element - this will throw the exception you're seeing.

Comment: @ChrisPhillips as soulcheck mentions, the error is caused because `lst` might have less than two elements. Just to be sure: don't forget that indexes in clojure start at `0`, that is: the first element is `(nth lst 0)`, the second is `(nth lst 1)` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, apart from defining all the functions before using them, may be declaring `invert-helper` before `invert`:

```
(declare invert-helper)

(defn invert [lst]
  (if (empty? lst)
    ()
    (cons (invert-helper lst) (invert (rest lst)))))

(defn invert-helper [lst]
  (list (nth lst 1) (first lst)))
```

You're also calling `(nth lst 1)` where `lst` may have only one element - this will throw an exception.